# How do you check if the time (hour) is equal to?

Tags: java, android

Basically I created a text (TextView) where the current time of the device is shown.

i want to put the time in a variable. And then check if the time is equal to (a specific time eg 14:15) when you click on the text a music starts singing.

CODE ⬇️

```
package com.example.simplecalculatorbyvalentinlearningapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class SeccondScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView h;
    TextView d;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_seccond_screen);


        //Sound
        final MediaPlayer betaaudio = MediaPlayer.create (this, R.raw.betaaudio);



    h = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hour);
    d = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date);


    //hour BETA CODE
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
    String dateTime = SimpleDateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(calendar.getTime());
    h.setText(dateTime);


    //date BETA CODE
    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
    dateTime = SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance().format(calendar.getTime());
    d.setText(dateTime);


    //start sound

       String vhour =  ;

        if(vhour == "trad" ) {

            h.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    betaaudio.start();

                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```

This is all the code.
I managed to do almost everything but I am stuck to the vhour variable to put the current time inside and then check with (if) if the time is equal to 14:15 for example, to make the code work inside the if, how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

you want to substring current hour from `datatime` variable
like this:

```
 String  dateTime = SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance().format(calendar.getTime()); 


 String currentTime =  dateTime.substring(10,16);
```

and you want put check statement inside onClickListener not out side it :

```
  h.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   if (currentTile.equals("14:43") {
                        betaaudio.start();
                     }
                }

         });
```

Comment: what os this error?  shouldn't I replace .equal with ==       ?

Comment: it's .equals not .equal

Comment: yes sorry but anyway don't work now the app crash

Comment: please attach an screenshot of what is the exception

Comment: you should look inside logcat tab to see your exception.

Comment: This is what I have added and what I have corrected for your code.

Comment: I add another coment with all new curent code

Comment: I think they are not any error except the condition not equal true 
so you can log or toast the two value of ( currentTime and 14:44) for example to check values

Comment: yes but it does not work anyway when I enter the application and go to the screen where there is this code when I press the button to enter this screen the app crashes. It didn't crash before

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/NEDHnn8


Surely there is an error in this part of the code because if I remove this part of the code the app doesn't crash anymore.

Comment: ok. you can see what the exception from logcat tab 
see the bottom of android studio and click on logcat tab to see you app logs and exceptions

Comment: https://ctxt.io/2/AACghSI7Fw


you can see the logcat here.

Comment: your exception is outOfBoundException:

because you declare simpleDateFormate but you don't use your formate on SimpleDataFormat

you can see 'simpleDateFormat' not use on SimpleDateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(calendar.getTime());
    h.setText(dateTime);

Comment: and what I need to do? For this?

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.simplecalculatorbyvalentinlearningapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class SeccondScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView h;
    TextView d;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_seccond_screen);


        //Sound
        final MediaPlayer betaaudio = MediaPlayer.create (this, R.raw.betaaudio);



    h = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hour);
    d = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date);


    //hour BETA CODE
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
    String dateTime = SimpleDateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(calendar.getTime());
    h.setText(dateTime);


    //date BETA CODE
    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
    dateTime = SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance().format(calendar.getTime());
    d.setText(dateTime);


    //start sound

        String currentTime =  dateTime.substring(10,16);

        h.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (currentTime.equals("14:43")) {
                    betaaudio.start();
                }
            }

        });







    }
}
```